# Combining rows of the same key into single array

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
    error
 0: [[0.1,0.4,-0.3]]
 1: [[-0.6,-0.3,0.2]]
 .
 .
 .
 99: [[0.4,-0.7,0.1]]
```

I would like to combine all values into a single array like this:

```
 [0.1,0.4,-0.3,-0.6,-0.3,0.2,...,0.4,-0.7,0.1]
```

Is there a fast way to do this using pandas or do I need to iterate over the data and build the array "manually" ?
The data order, in this case, is not important.

In a more general case, how to combine arrays that don't have the same size (e.g. row 0 contains an array of 3 elements, row 1 contains an array of 6 elements,etc...) ?

Comment: have you tried anything before asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
L = np.array(df['error'].values.tolist()).ravel().tolist()
print (L)
[0.1, 0.4, -0.3, -0.6, -0.3, 0.2, 0.4, -0.7, 0.1]
```

More general solutions with `str[0]` for select nested `lists`:

```
print (df)
               error
0   [[0.1,0.4,-0.3]]
1      [[-0.6,-0.3]]
99  [[0.4,-0.7,0.1]]

from  itertools import chain

L = list(chain.from_iterable(df['error'].str[0]))
print (L)
[0.1, 0.4, -0.3, -0.6, -0.3, 0.4, -0.7, 0.1]

L =  np.concatenate(df['error'].str[0].values).tolist()
print (L)
[0.1, 0.4, -0.3, -0.6, -0.3, 0.4, -0.7, 0.1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[0.1,0.4,-0.3],[-0.6,-0.3,0.2]])

df.values.flatten()
```

will return :
array([ 0.1,  0.4, -0.3, -0.6, -0.3,  0.2])

if you would like to append the element by column

```
df.values.flatten(order='F')
```

then it will return:
array([ 0.1, -0.6,  0.4, -0.3, -0.3,  0.2])

Comment: This works if the rows are of shape (N,) but if they are of shape (N,1), you need jezrael's solution